# YouTube - Play automatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an UIButton. When this button is pressed, I load a WebView with the youtube video:

```
- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:[MyButton frame]];
    NSString *htmlString = @"<html> (...) </html>"; // HTML w/ the YouTube iFrame
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;
    [webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
    [self.view addSubView:webView];
}
```

The problem is that when it happen, I have this result:
[image]

I want to start playing the video right after I load the WebView.

Any tip/solution?

Thanks!

Comment: You do say `webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = YES`... so that might be your problem.

Comment: Actually, @Dustin, using `webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO` the video still needs to press play to start running.

Comment: Right, but if you explicitly write it out that it requires user action then no matter what it won't work. Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1617723/1487063. It looks like you just need to reload your web page.

Comment: Still not working, @Dustin. I already tried to follow every tutorial presented in the internet, but no one starts playing the youtube video.

Comment: Try adding the subview before you do anything else.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but it's not solving the YouTube "touch to play" problem.

Comment: I just used http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/audio-video/how-to-play-youtube-videos-within-an-application with the second answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617723/how-to-play-youtube-movie-on-an-iphone-application-when-tapped-on-uitableviewcel?rq=1 and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating an html page that is a stand alone page that will use the youtube player api. Since your creating an html page already just have the uiwebview use the stand alone site that you have created and then you can use the autoplay features built into the youtube player. I can give more detail but if you can not use a stand alone html site as your option that this will be a worthless answer and thus anything else that I add will not help you.